# Solving quadratic equations without the quadratic forumla

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the following equation, in terms of $q$, without using the quadratic formula?

$t - (m-q)^2 = v - (m-p)^2$

I asked a similar question this morning (about the quadratic formula), but wondered if there was another approach, for the sake of completeness really!

Many thanks.

Comment: We do not need the quadratic formula.

Comment: You can solve this for $q$ explicitly with some easy manipulations.

Comment: Excellent and helpful answers from all, many thanks. I've accepted @NicholasStoll's answer because it also links to the derivation of the quadratic formula. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of what you had in your previous answer, here is a way to solve this without using the quadratic formula, although we will actually derive the quadratic formula in the process.

$$t-(m-q)^2 = v - (m-p)^2$$
Start out by moving everything except $(m-q)^2$ to the RHS and switching signs on both sides to obtain:

$$(m-q)^2 = (m-p)^2 + t - v$$
Now, $(m-q)^2 = (q-m)^2$, so we can rewrite this as

$$(q-m)^2 = (m-p)^2 + t - v$$
Then take the square root of both sides and we get
$$q-m = \pm \sqrt{(m-p)^2 + t - v)}$$
($\pm$ being shorthand for the two solutions, one with a $+$, one with a $-$)
And solving from here is a matter of moving $m$ to the other side.

But what you will see if you expand it out exactly as done in the previous question, is that in effect this derives the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

Since our equation has very special form, we do not need the quadratic formula to "isolate" $q$.

The equation has shape $A-(m-q)^2=B$. Rewrite it as $(m-q)^2=A-B$, and then as $q-m=\pm\sqrt{A-B}$, which yields $q=m\pm\sqrt{A-B}$.

Comment: While it does indeed have this very special form, for quadratics in a single variable, it seems that we could always arrive at this form by completing the square.

Comment: The form is special in that the "completing the square" has already been done.

Comment: Quite right.  +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

$(m-q)^2=t-v+(m-p)^2$, so:
 $m-q=\pm\sqrt{t-v+(m-p)^2}$ and finally: $q=m\mp\sqrt{t-v+(m-p)^2}$